# Show that if the roots of the equation $(a^2+b^2)x^2 + 2x(ac+bd) +c^2+d^2$ are real, they are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help. I am approaching it through the discriminant way, but I am struck. I TRIED IN THE FOLLOWING WAY:
$$D\geq 0 $$

Comment: The equation is $(ax+c)^2+(bx+d)^2=0$. The sum of two squares can only be $0$ if both are $0$

Answer (score 8):

Note that 
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2.$$

**Remarks:** $1.$ This is a very useful identity.

$2.$ Please see the comment by L.F. for a (much) nicer solution of your problem than the discriminant approach.

Comment: One of my favorite identities :)

Comment: This is called Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity( http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that the discriminant

$$4(ac+bd)^2 - (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$

is non-positive for all real values of $a, b, c, d$.

**Hint:** If the roots are real, the discriminant is non-negative.

Thus, the discriminant is 0.

Hence the roots are equal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Gah! Thanks!